# What is the difference between несколько and много?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Здравствуйте,

What is the difference between несколько and много in your opinion and when are these two words used best (situation?)

Большое спасибо

Comment: Do you by any chance mean the difference between **несколько** and ***немного***? Seeing as you're very unlikely to ever have to choose with any difficulty between the word for "several" and the word for "many".

Comment: Is the difference between those two words smaller than in the несколько and много case?

Comment: **Много** means "many". **Несколько** means "several", which in many contexts is quite the opposite of "many". I just don't see how choosing between the two could ever be a problem, unless one hasn't got their meanings quite right. Now **немного** "a few", on the other hand, is somewhat synonymous with **несколько**.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Please note that though "несколько" and "немного" are quite similar, you can use "немного" for both countable and uncountable objects, but "несколько" is only for countable ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Несколько" means "several", "some", "a few". "Много" means "many", "a lot". So the difference must be obvious.

Comment: Большое спасибо